# Why query does not fail with nonexistent column in subquery?

Tags: mysql

I misspelled in my query and faced with MySQL's strange behaviour.

```
create table aaa (id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
                  amount int not null, 
                  other_column varchar(20)) engine=InnoDB
create table bbb (aaa_id bigint not null, 
                  comment varchar(200), 
                  key(aaa_id)) engine=InnoDB; 
insert into aaa(other_column, amount) values ('hello, world', 12), 
                                             ('second string', 15), 
                                             ('one more', 100);
insert into bbb value (2, 'no 2s!');
```

The following query produces `null` result (I typed 'id' instead of 'aaa_id'):

```
select sum(amount) from aaa where id not in (select id from bbb);
```

"Maybe 'id' has special meaning for MySQL", I thought. But, the following query executes normally and returns `127` (as if subquery returns empty result):

```
select sum(amount) from aaa where id not in (select other_column from bbb);
```

The following queries produce expected result: first one fails with `Unknown column 'id2' in 'field list'`, and the second one returns `112`:

```
select sum(amount) from aaa where id not in (select id2 from bbb);
select sum(amount) from aaa where id not in (select aaa_id from bbb);
```

As it can be seen, MySQL somehow executes subquery if the column exists in the outer query. But what the meaning of those columns in the subquery?

Tested on 5.1.70 and 5.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
select sum(amount)
from aaa
where id not in (select id from bbb);
```

Is interpreted as:

```
select sum(aaa.amount)
from aaa
where aaa.id not in (select aaa.id from bbb);
```

because `bbb.id` does not exist.  When writing SQL, I suggest that you always use table aliases.  The query that you thought you were writing:

```
select sum(aaa.amount)
from aaa
where aaa.id not in (select bbb.id from bbb);
```

would generate the error you expect.

Comment: I think I understood. In the first case (`aaa.id`), `not in` condition discards every row in the `aaa` table. And `sum`, as an aggregate function, returns `null`. In the `aaa.other_column` case, evidently, MySQL accepts every row due to type mismatch between `id` column and `other_column`.

Comment: @ErnestSadykov . . . Yes.  That is the follow-on logic.  I just wanted to explain that the problem is in how the query is parsed.  It doesn't do what you want -- and you seem to have a good understanding of what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the `bbb` table like this:

```
create table bbb (aaa_id bigint not null, 
                  ^^^^^^
```

why would you use

```
select sum(amount) from aaa where id not in (select id from bbb);
                                                    ^^
```

then instead? The DB's not telepathic, it can't read your mind. If you tell it to use field `x` in a table, then it's going to need `x` to actually exist, and won't randomly pick some OTHER field.

The subquery COULD "reach out" and pick up field names from the outer/parent query, if tell the DB to do so, e.g.

```
SELECT id
FROM aaa
WHERE 
   id in (SELECT ... FROM bbb WHERE aaa.id = bbb.somefield)
```

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want the DB to read my mind. I want it to fail, but it does not and returns strange (null) result instead.